Why doesn't "for this week" sound natural?
I am working part-time as a retail clerk. I work only three shifts a week. I had my third shift today. When leaving, I said to my colleague.
(1a) I said, "This is my third shift. I am done for this week."
He corrected me by saying, "You are done for the week."
Why doesn't "for this week" sound natural to native speakers?

Your colleague is wrong; it's fine to say 'I am done for this week'.

"This is my third shift. I am done for the week"  implies that your normal schedule is to work three shifts per week.
If you said "I am done for this week" a listener might infer that this week is different from other weeks, as that implication is more salient with "this" than it is with "the".
P.S.  It would be more idiomatic to say "That was my third shift. I am done for the week."  We use "that was" when speaking of things that are "behind us" time-wise.  For example, when a taxi cab drives by very close to the curb and splashes water from a puddle onto the sidewalk, narrowly missing you in your nice clothes, afterwards you'd say "That was a close call!" not "This was a close call!"

Both versions sound fine, with hardly any difference.  If I have to think of a difference,  it could be that with this, some people may expect another part to match this week:
This is my third shift. I am done for this week; see you next week.
With the,
This is my third shift. I am done for the week.
There are no expectations for a follow-up to match the week although I recognise that see you next week can also be moved to this version.
